# "Display over other apps"

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, mobile

I'm not a regular Android user, but I'm building an Android app and the latest versions of Android now show a pop up when you first install & run an app saying "Display over other apps" with a toggle for several built-in apps and my apps.

I've been googling for a while and haven't been able to find any information as to these basic questions:

- What is this?
- Does my app need to display over other apps?
- If not, can I disable this pop up from coming up?

Any links to documentation would be great.

Comment: Was mainly seeing this in React Native dev mode, but it's not in release versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your application asks for [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission! If your app doesn't need it, you can remove following line from your Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Answer (score 4):

your device OS is above the android veriosn 6.0 and sometimes devices gives as that pop-up when you will ask for permission. You can check this link https://screenoverlaydetected.com/draw-over-other-apps/
better option is **format your device** as it will show in every apps.